# error when trying to connect to my websitename(Centos)

Tags: python, centos, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to set up very basic http server on my hosting(centos)

The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

 class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')


httpd = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Everything looks normal: ss -t -a -n

LISTEN   0         5                          0.0.0.0:8080                     0.0.0.0:*

But when im trying to get to my websitename:8080 nothing is happening and i get connection timed out response.
I've been googling about http, networking, even centos for a few days, got lots of usefull information but i still have no idea what's going on here.
Ty for your time!

Comment: try httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler), localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @CaptainCaveman. Didn't help :(

Comment: are you actually going to websitename:8080? or ip address:8080?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman both, actually, tried both

Comment: www.mysite.com:8080 won't work unless you have a DNS server resolving the domain name to your IP.

Comment: Nginx is listening on 80 and i get a response when going to websitename:80 and myip:80, could it be that he is doing something to prevent other connections ?

Comment: Once you think the script is running, try lsof -i :8080 to find out what, if anything is listening on 8080. In your example you said 8080 not 80.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman did it

python3.8 761 h106719406    3u  IPv4 2894712300      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)

Comment: Ok, so your script is listening on 8080.

Comment: Try a different port. http://localhost:8000 maybe to check if there are conflicts.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman i use shared hosting and my server IP is basically shared between multiple websites. Meaby i only have access to nginx:80 that is somehow resolving addresses.. but how do i even google this problem

Comment: So the IP is static? Did you try another port at the same IP?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman i thought you were suggesting using localhost or 127.0.0.1 inside httpserver(('here'...
And i made a mistake about nginx - when i'm going to webname:80 it's responding just fine, but when i go to ip:80 i get rejected. Sorry

Comment: Try nslookup webname.com and see what IP is returned. Then browse to that IP.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman ok there was something wrong with my hosting, just configured another one and everything is working like a charm. TY for your effort!